# How can I create recipe in calibre to fetch full content from xml instead webpage?

Tags: python, xml, rss, calibre

I  have a xml rss feed like below,

http://www.prajavani.net/rss.xml

where description contains body of news/article and also contains image. when i create recipe in calibre, it fetches content from web page using link in xml, but it doesnt fetch correctly and doesnt read image. But xml contains all content need title, image, body(description), image. How can i make recipe to fetch every thing from xml itself instead downloading from each webpage.

hope understood my situation.

Regards , Abdul

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: My apologies, I did thought how can i ask with example but couldn't get one easest than above one.  Hoped if some using Calibre might understand. Hence there are no forum for calibre I droped question here. Thank u for response.

Answer (score 0):

Just got answer.

**Set**

```
use_embedded_content = True
```